# Stopping Event to take place on a div on buttton click

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have 5 `div` elements with a property that when the space bar is pressed, all the `div` elements change to a random color. But I want to add another button in each div which when pressed should stop the color from changing in that div.
In a nutshell, I want to stop the event from happenning.

```js
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    setBg();
    setBg1();
    setBg2();
    setBg3();
    setBg4();
  }
}

const setBg = () => {
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("divcolor").style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
  color.innerHTML = "#" + randomColor;
}

const setBg1 = () => {
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("divcolor1").style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
  color1.innerHTML = "#" + randomColor;
}

const setBg2 = () => {
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("divcolor2").style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
  color2.innerHTML = "#" + randomColor;
}

const setBg3 = () => {
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("divcolor3").style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
  color3.innerHTML = "#" + randomColor;
}

const setBg4 = () => {
  const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.getElementById("divcolor4").style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
  color4.innerHTML = "#" + randomColor;
}

var btn = document.getElementById("genNew")

btn.addEventListener("click", setBg);
btn.addEventListener("click", setBg1);
btn.addEventListener("click", setBg2);
btn.addEventListener("click", setBg3);
btn.addEventListener("click", setBg4);

setBg();
setBg1();
setBg2();
setBg3();
setBg4();
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" id="divcolor" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
    <h1><span id="color"></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="divcolor1">
    <h1><span id="color1"></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="divcolor2">
    <h1><span id="color2"></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="divcolor3">
    <h1><span id="color3"></span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="divcolor4">
    <h1><span id="color4"></span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have any other request for this? I think you have not reviewed my last answer. Let me know your further request and feedback on my answer. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways. One is to set a certain flag on the clicked element's `dataset`, which you can then read at the next space/button click.

Some remarks about your code:

- Avoid code repetition. Make one function for all five elements, not five functions.
- Don't try to apply style by nesting HTML elements (`h1`, `span`). Certainly using `h1` here is inappropriate. Use CSS styling to set the font size if that is your aim.
- Don't use `e.keyCode`: its use is [no longer recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keycode). Use the more modern `e.key` property.
- Don't use `id` attributes with sequential numbers as suffix. Those are almost always a code smell. Instead use CSS classes.

Here I use `dataset.frozen` (a freely chosen attribute name) to remember which boxes are "frozen". Clicking them again will unfreeze them. To better visualise this flag, I also toggle the border width of the clicked element:

```js
let row = document.querySelector(".row");
var btn = document.getElementById("genNew")

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.key == "Spacebar") setBg();
}

function setBg() {
    for (const div of row.children) {
        if (div.dataset.frozen) continue;
        const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        div.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
        div.textContent = "#" + randomColor;
    }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", setBg);

row.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let div = e.target.closest(".col");
    if (!div) return; // Not clicked on (or in) a .col element.
    // toggle a flag and the border:
    div.dataset.frozen = div.dataset.frozen ? "" : "yes";
    div.style.borderWidth = (div.dataset.frozen ? 5 : 0) + "px"; 
});

setBg();
```

```css
.col { 
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 0px red solid;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>

<button id="genNew">Generate [space]</button>
```

Comment: Any feedback on this answer,  @hritikpawar?

Answer (score -1):

We use global variable to save divs' status which will be referenced to set background of div according to its value.
We check div's statuses when key space is pressed, and emit setBg function to color-change-unblocked event divs.
Here is full code of one html.
I assumed you have your own css

```
<html>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" onclick="disable(this);" id="div1"><h1><span id="color1"></span></h1></div>
    <div class="col" onclick="disable(this);" id="div2"><h1><span id="color2"></span></h1></div>
    <div class="col" onclick="disable(this);" id="div3"><h1><span id="color3"></span></h1></div>
    <div class="col" onclick="disable(this);" id="div4"><h1><span id="color4"></span></h1></div>
    <div class="col" onclick="disable(this);" id="div5"><h1><span id="color5"></span></h1></div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
    //initial array of blocked statuses of divs
    var div_array = new Array(); // array of blocked statuses of divs
    div_array["div1"]=true;   
    div_array["div2"]=true;
    div_array["div3"]=true;
    div_array["div4"]=true;
    div_array["div5"]=true;
    document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 32){
        for (var key in div_array) {
            if(div_array[key])  // check if div has been blocked from changing color event
              setBg(key);    //set background of div which has passed div_id
        }
      }
  }
  function setBg(div_id){
    const randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    const parent = document.getElementById(div_id);
    const children = parent.children[0];
    parent.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
    children.innerHTML = "#" + randomColor;
  }
  function disable(item){     //block changing color of selected div on click
    const id = item.getAttribute('id');
    div_array[id] = false;
  }
  
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You are misusing an array. An array should be used with numerical indexes.

Comment: @trincot this is assosiative array. There is no specified rule that we shouldn't use associative array. https://www.xul.fr/javascript/associative.php

Comment: There is no "associative array" in JavaScript. If you need key/value pairs, you should use a plain object. It works on arrays, because arrays are extended objects, but since you don't use any array-specific feature, this is bad practice. Just use a plain object for this.

Comment: From the link you are referring to: `So we can create an associative array with the "Object" reserved word`. In this code `Array` is being used instead of an `Object`

Comment: @hritik any feedback of my answer?

Comment: It worked totally fine for me. I got the approach of how it works. But can you teach me how do I enable the div again onclick. Should I create another function to Enable it.

Comment: @hritikpawar its very simple if you followed my answer. You should set opposite value of status when you click. So in my answer just update `disable()` method to have `div_array[id] = !div_array[id]` instead of `div_array[id]=false`

Comment: @hritikpawar please let me know if you have checked this.